# How to print the second last line of a file using awk

Tags: linux, awk

I have multiple files with different number or records in each. I want an awk command to print the second last line of them and perform some change. I want something like this:(this one doesn't work of course)

```
awk '( NR == FNR-1 ), $0","' *.txt
```

Comment: *perform some change* - what change exactly?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Append a comma at the end of that line is what I want in this case. Didn't think it would matter though :)

Comment: should each file be modified in-place?

Comment: Yes. My main focus is the selection of the second last line.. i.e "( NR == FNR-1 )" this part in my command. What is wrong in that.. But yes I do want to modify them in place.
In the description I said I want to print the second last line to just test it on one file and see how it work.. and so that I would later add the part where it adds the comma at the end of that line.

Comment: @αғsнιη Thanks! The awk solution in the mentioned link worked. I missed that page probably because of the different keywords used I suppose.

Comment: `ed` or `ex/vi` would be a better choice IMHO e.g. `printf '$-1 s/$/,/\nwq\n' | ed -s file`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`awk` reads records as they come and has no notion of how far from the end those  records are if it has not read them yet (extra records could very well  be added after it reads and processes the current record).

Contrary to `sed`, it cannot even tell which is the last record (`sed` has the `$` address which it actually implements by internally reading one record in advance so it knows which is the last one).

You can however  do some processing at the end in the special `END` statement, or with GNU `awk`, after having processed each input file (in the `ENDFILE` statement).

So you can save the last two records while you're processing them, and then in the `END`/`ENDFILE` statement, recall the penultimate one from where you've saved it.

For instance:

```
awk '{prevlast = last; last = $0}
     END {if (NR >= 2) print "penultimate:", prevlast}' < input
```

Or:

```
gawk '{prevlast = last; last = $0}
      ENDFILE {
       if (FNR >= 2) print "penultimate for", FILENAME ":", prevlast
      }' file1 file2
```

Or  to generalise it for the n<sup>th</sup> from the end:

```
awk -v n=2 '{saved[NR % n] = $0}
     END {if (NR >= n) print saved[(NR + 1) % n]}' < input

gawk -v n=2 '{saved[FNR % n] = $0}
     ENDFILE {if (FNR >= n) print saved[(FNR + 1) % n]}' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 0):

To append comma `,` at the end of second-to-last line with modifying each file in-place.

**`sed`** solution:

Sample `file1.txt`:

```
C2-C1 1.5183
C3-C2 1.49
C3-C1 1.4991
O4-C3 1.4104
C1-C2-C3 59.78
```

---

Sample `file2.txt`:

```
C2-C1 1.5052
C3-C2 1.505
C3-C1 1.5037
S4-C3 1.7976
C1-C2-C3 59.95
```

---

```
sed -i 'x; ${s/.*/&,/;p;x}; 1d' file*.txt
```

---

Viewing results:

```
$ head file[12].txt
==> file1.txt <==
C2-C1 1.5183
C3-C2 1.49
C3-C1 1.4991
O4-C3 1.4104,
C1-C2-C3 59.78

==> file2.txt <==
C2-C1 1.5052
C3-C2 1.505
C3-C1 1.5037
S4-C3 1.7976,
C1-C2-C3 59.95
```